# onload array of images in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, onload

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    img[i] = new Image();

    img[i].onload = function(){console.log(i); myFunc(i)}; // 10 every iteration
    img[i].src = someUrl;
}
```

I need to start myFunc with index of the current img. But when the myFunc started i is already 10. How can I do what I whant?

Comment: i think its not possible because you define i  in for scope...are toy define i in other place of your code?

Comment: @combo_ci of course it is possible

Comment: use *let i=0* ,or an IIFE

Comment: @tsh yes it does. there's a new `i` binding for each iteration of the loop if you use `let`

Comment: @tsh i know what im doing